# function call in Angular using typescript creates infinite loop

Tags: angular, angularjs, typescript

I have a usecase as below: My objective is to update the array in `if` and `else` case.

The main array(**cis**) looks like below

[image]

.html

```
<sample-container  [cis]="filterCi(currentBaseline.cis, currentBaseline)"> </sample-container>
```

.ts
This function runs a map over the array provided above and returns the same structure with all the objects execpt those with property `checked:false` (removed from the structure) by doing a recursive call on children everytime.

```
//retrieveChildren

retreiveChildren(children: Structure[]) : Structure[] {
  let filteredCis =  children && children.filter((ci) =>{
      if(ci.children && ci.children.length > 0){
         retreiveChildren(ci.children);
      }
      return ci.checked === true;
    }) ;
  return filteredCis;
}

//filterCi function

filterCi(cis: Structure[], baseline: Baseline): Structure[] {
    if(baseline.isHideElementsActivated){
      let newArray = [...cis]
      let result =  newArray.filter(ci => ci.checked === true).map((item,index) => {
        return {
          ...item,
          children : retreiveChildren(item.children)
        }
      })
      console.log("Result array...." , result)
      return result;
    }else{
      return cis;
    }
}
```

The issue I am facing here is, the `filterCi` function is calling infinitely. Initially, I thought it is because of the recursive call, but even after removing recursion it results in infinite loop.

Finally, I could conclude that it is because of `map` function used inside filterCi.
Why is this behavior and how can I resolve it?

Comment: It's more due to the method retreiveChildren (call inside the map function) but which call itself on filter of data. Could we have an idea/ sample of the data manipulated ?

Comment: I observed it is not because of retreiveChildren function. Because when i replace return value of map function by this return {
          ...item,
          children : item.children && item.children.length > 0 ? item.children.filter(element => element.checked === true) : item.children
        }                                                                                                                                                 I have infinite loop even in this case @jeremy-denis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are calling a method from an input binding in a template it will be evaluating on every change detection cycle, as angular has no way of knowing that this is a pure function (see: https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496).

I think this may be the problem you are seeing. To resolve you can use an angular pipe: https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Edit: You should be able to treat the transform method of the pipe as the filterCi method creating a pipe like:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filterCis'
})
export class FilterCisPipe implements PipeTransform {

  public transform(cis: Structure[], baseline: Baseline): Structure[] {
    if(baseline.isHideElementsActivated){
      let newArray = [...cis]
      let result =  newArray.filter(ci => ci.checked === true).map((item,index) => {
        return {
          ...item,
          children : retreiveChildren(item.children)
        }
      })
      console.log("Result array...." , result)
      return result;
    }else{
      return cis;
    }
  }

  private retreiveChildren(children: Structure[]) : Structure[] {
    let filteredCis =  children && children.filter((ci) =>{
        if(ci.children && ci.children.length > 0){
           retreiveChildren(ci.children);
        }
        return ci.checked === true;
      }) ;
    return filteredCis;
  }

}
```

Then after registering the pipe in the app module. Use it in the template like:

`<sample-container  [cis]="currentBaseline.cis | filterCi:currentBaseline"> </sample-container>`

Comment: I see pipes are used only in case of rendering values. How can i do that while calling the function ? Because in my case its the function .

Comment: Hey, I've edited the post to show how I would create the pipe, hope that helps! Reply to this if you have any trouble

Comment: Thanks a lot Jonathan . This really helped

Answer (score 2):

I tried your solution for `retreiveChildren` and it worked for me with the data you provided in the beginning of your question.

I agree @Jonathan with the statement that you shouldn't call the filter function from the HTML directly. You should use a Pipe as he mentioned.

But I found a bug in your implementation. Your function filters the parent nodes accordingly but it doesn't have any effect on the children. You should assign the return value of your recursion to the children to remove all children with are not checked.

That could look like following:

```
retrieveChildren(children: Structure[]): Structure[]{
  const filteredCis = children && children.filter((ci) => {
    if (!ci.checked) {
      return false;
    }
    
    ci.children = retrievedChildren(ci.children);
    return true;
  });

  return filteredCis;
}
```

I refactored your function a bit to be more readable in my opinion.

Comment: Could you please show me how to use pipe in my case? I see that pipe is being being used to render values inside component. I am not sure how to use it for function call @Batajus